# Get all text in div + dropdownList selected Item

Tags: jquery

I'm using the code below to get all text in a div, the div contain many textbox & label.

```
var sResult = "";
$(".formItem").children().each( function(){
    var sOutput = $(this).text();
if(sOutput == "") 
    sOutput = $(this).val();
if(sOutput != "")
sResult += " "+sOutput;
});
$(".TXTresult").val(sResult);
```

The code is work fine, but I had a problem when use the code whit dropdownlist inside the div. I get all the Items in dropdownList but not only the selected item!!!

(Please noted that the Textbox, label & dropdownList are generate by code, no fix ID.)

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 1):

```
var sResult = "";
$(".formItem").children().each( function(){
  if($(this).is("select"))
       var sOutput = $(this).val();
  else{
    var sOutput = $(this).text();
  }
});
$(".TXTresult").val(sResult);
```

Comment: You could have added input cases ;)

Comment: @BorisDelormas absolutely right, i thought of doing so but then i left it to the OP as he has only asked about the DDL `:)`